# Angular Jest - Test passes, but should fail: Unhandled Promise rejection: expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Tags: angular, jestjs

When running this simple test, an error message is shown, but the overall result is PASSED.

How to prevent? Yes, there are similar posts, but look different in my situation. It's about waiting for the result. I tried the suggestions.

In summary: clicking on a button should trigger a component method go() [calling a service] that should give a new value to a component property.

In this case the faked service is NOT an Observable.

The component:

```
export class OneComponent {
  currentValue = 123;

  constructor(private incrementerService2: IncrementerService2) { }

  public go(): void {
    this.currentValue = this.incrementerService2.increment();
  }
}
```

Angular template:

```
<p>
  Input: <input [(ngModel)]="currentValue" type="number" id="count"/>
  <button (click)="go()" id="increment-button">Go!</button>
</p>
```

Test code:

```
describe('OneComponent basic test', () => {
  let component: OneComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OneComponent>;
  let fakeIncrementServiceMock: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fakeIncrementServiceMock = {
      increment: jest.fn()
    }
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ OneComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: IncrementerService2, useValue: fakeIncrementServiceMock } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OneComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it( 'click gives new number', () => {
    let currentCount = 123;
    setFormElementValue( fixture.nativeElement, '#count', String(currentCount));

    jest.spyOn(fakeIncrementServiceMock, 'increment').mockImplementation(() => 246)

    clickFormElement(fixture, '#increment-button');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then( () => {
      expect( getFormElementValue( fixture.nativeElement, '#count')).toEqual( '146');
    });
  });
 });
```

I did both `it( ..., async()` => and `it( ..., ()`.

The result is 1 PASSED test, although the error is of course:

```
console.error
    Unhandled Promise rejection: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    
    Expected: "146"
    Received: "246" ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: JestAssertionError: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is asynchronous, you need to await the promise :

```
it( 'click gives new number', async () => {
    let currentCount = 123;
    setFormElementValue( fixture.nativeElement, '#count', String(currentCount));

    jest.spyOn(fakeIncrementServiceMock, 'increment').mockImplementation(() => 246)

    clickFormElement(fixture, '#increment-button');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable().then( () => { // await this
      expect( getFormElementValue( fixture.nativeElement, '#count')).toEqual( '146');
    });
});
```